# Bitwise OR vs Logical OR

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

in C, is

```
if((d[i] != 1) && (d[i] != 2))
```

same as

```
if(d[i] != (1 | 2))
```

and why is

```
if(d[i] != (1 || 2))
```

rejected by the compiler?

is there a way to simplify the first statement, if I want to check for many constants? which to say check whether d[i] is 1,2,3,4,5. So I would reject it if d[i] is e.g. 6.

Comment: What you said is not right. `d[i] != (1 | 2)` is not same as `(d[i] != 1) && (d[i] != 2)`.

Comment: Hi, thank you all for the answers. I had some serious misconceptions about the | and || operators. I was trying to simplify the `if((d[i] != 1) && (d[i] != 2))` but it appears I mistakenly changed the value of the constants I was checking it against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, They are not same. `if((d[i] != 1) && (d[i] != 2))` **cannot** be further simplified.

Lets come to other codes.   `if(d[i] != (1 | 2))` it first performs `(1|2)`, which results in `3`. and then performs comparison `if(d[i] != 3)`, you certainly don't want that, right?

Now In `if(d[i] != (1 || 2))` , first operation done is  `(1 || 2)` it results in `true` (type is boolean) and your statement effectively becomes `if(d[i] != true) //comparing int to boolean`, due to type mismatch compiler *warns* against  it.

If you want to check for multiple numbers, use a for loop and array as

```
int constants[]=  {1,2,3,4,5}; //constants to check against
int ar_size = sizeof(constants) / sizeof(constants[0]); //ar_size will adjust to array size, you can use vector for simplification


bool inArray = false;  //default is false.
for (int it_i = 0; i < ar_size; it_i++)
{
    if (constants[it_i] == d[i]) //Checking is done here
        inArray = true;
}
//just use inArray to find if element was in constants[] or not
if (inArray)
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I had some serious misconceptions about the | and || operators, thanks for the clarification

Comment: @QuekYufei, as you are new user, please remember to mark the answer you find best as Accepted answer, for reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

1) No. `1 | 2` is `3` (you can test this by printing it out) so `if(d[i] != (1 | 2))` does the same thing as `if(d[i] != 3)`

2) It shouldn't be. `1 || 2` should be `1`, so `if(d[i] != (1 || 2))` should do the same thing as `if(d[i] != 1)`. If you get an error for this, then I suspect that's because you're using your compiler's "treat warnings as errors" option (`-Werror` for gcc or clang).

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer**

> is there a way to simplify the first statement, if I want to check for
>   many constants? which to say check whether d[i] is 1,2,3,4,5. So I
>   would reject it if d[i] is e.g. 6.

Absolutely:

```
if ((d[i] >= 1) && (d[i] <= 5))
```

See,  it's really not that complicated. The compiler can likely optimize the heck out of this.

For what it's worth, detecting `x in [1..5]` is actually a very difficult expression to optimize with bitmask logic. If you write out a Karnaugh Map for the lower three bits of the integer range, nothing helpful shows up.  The best I could simplify it to is this:

```
if (4 >= (unsigned)(d[i]-1))
```

I compiled some code in Visual Studio to see how it would optimize `(x >= 1) && (x <= 5)` in a retail build.  It optimizes exactly like the expression above.  That is:  `((x-1) <  4)`

Comment: hi,thanks for the answer. But what if I wanted to check, say, 1,3,5,7,8,10. then using the <= and >= wouldnt help. I was basically trying to simplify typing out multiple && statements

Comment: @QuekYufei - My advice would be to  Optimize the expression as best as possible - while still keeping the code *readable* and *maintainable*.  The compiler (with the right flags set), can do some amazing optimizations for you.  So if it means you have to say `if (x == 1) || (x == 3) ... || (x ==10)`, then so be it. At least the next guy who has to fix a bug in your code won't have to guess what `(x < 11) && ((x & 1) && !(x & 0x80))` means.

Comment: @QuekYufei - You *can* use a Karnaugh Map  (google it) to help reduce your expression. In the case of evaluating a set of integers, it will help you write complicated bitmask logic.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

In a 8-bit number, `1` is represented as:

```
0000 0001
```

`2` is represented as

```
0000 0010
```

The bitwise OR of those two numbers results in

```
0000 0011
```

which is `3`.

Hence,

`d[i] != (1 | 2)` is the same as `d[i] != 3`. That is, obviously, very different from `(d[i] != 1) && (d[i] != 2)`.

```
if(d[i] != (1 || 2))
```

should not be rejected by the compiler. That statement is equivalent to:

```
if(d[i] != 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Condition 1.**

```
if((d[i] != 1) && (d[i] != 2))
```

This will check both condition `d[i] !=1` and `d[i]!=2` that is if d[i] not equal to 1 and 2 condition will run.
If first condition fails it will not check d[i] != 2.

**Condition 2.**

```
if(d[i] != (1 | 2))
```

here (1 | 2) will return 3.

```
1==>        0001  
2==>        0010   
           ------
Bitwise OR= 0011 ==> result will be 3
```

means it will check `d[i] !=3`

**Condition 3.**

```
if(d[i] != (1 || 2))
```

1||2 will return TRUE so it will give you error.

as d[i] is having integer value and you are trying to compare it with Boolean value which cause error.

Answer (score 0):

To check a variable against multiple values, the variable must be specified each time as in `a == 1 || a == 2 || ...` or `a != 1 && a != 2 && ...`.

Specifying only constants as in `a != (1 || 2 ||..)` will not give the expected result, because `1 || 2` is expanded to 1 (Refer to [Short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)). Compiler may give warning because it looks like an unlikely (unintended) construct.

Answer (score 0):

**d[i]** is integral value, and result of **(1 || 2)** is boolean *true*. Comparison of boolean and integral value in **if(d[i] != (1 || 2))** makes no sense to compiler.

Answer (score 0):

In C  `if((d[i] != 1) && (d[i] != 2))` implies that this condition is true if and only if d[i] is neither equal to 1 nor d[i] is equal to 2(Both conditions have to be satisfied simultaneously).

which is not same as `if(d[i] != (1 | 2))` as this implies that this condition is true if and only if d[i] is not equal to bitwise OR of 1 and 2 which is 0001|0010=0011 (3).So indirectly it is checking if d[i] is not equal to 3.

`if(d[i] != (1 || 2))` is not rejected by compiler try `gcc <filename.c>` and execute the `a.out` file. This will check d[i] with exclusive OR of 1 and 2 which is 1.So indirectly this condition evaluates to if d[i] is not equal to 1.

Coming to your final question your condition can be easily evaluated by this check:
`if((d[i]>=1) && (d[i]<=5))` where 1 is the initial value and 5 is the final value of your check.